# Making A quadradic factoring tool in python and a guess and check approach shows a value error

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, math

The code is so close to working but, I just can't seem to fix the error called "IndexError: list index out of range", What I want this to do is to check through every factor on one number and through a list add every single possible combination of numbers in that list to find two numbers in the said list that add to make the other number (this is how you would solve factoring for a quadratic).

````
def Diamond_problem(x2,x):
    for i in range(1, x2 + 1):
       if x2 % i == 0:
           Factor_list.append(i)
    for i in Factor_list:
        for j in Factor_list:
            if (i + j) == x:
                print(Factor_list[i], Factor_list[j])```
````

Comment: I have Factor_list = [] above, it just did not copy sorry

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question. Put the triple backticks on separate lines.

Comment: You are mixing up iterating over the indices of a list and iterating over the values. `i` is a value.

Comment: So if I understood the task correctly, you just want `print(i, j)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the factors, Just do

```
print(i, j)
```

instead of

```
print(Factor_list[i], Factor_list[j])
```